# Is it time for [jumping] to take the plunge?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

Not only does the [jumping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jumping) tag lack any formal description, but looking through the the questions there, I see posts of every sort. Video game 'jumping' mechanic seems to dominate a slight majority, but there is really no equilibrium of question types and for a few examples there are questions of:

- Changing audio without it skipping in Windows Media
- Dropdown jumps on focus when scrolling
- Page jumps on layer click
- HTML5 Video Div Jumping to Right then Back into Place on Load
- Python: Jumping back to the first line
- Tabs Jumping when clicked
- Issues Getting GameObject to Jump properly
- Make a non-nested div not jump at window resize

I would suggest either letting go of `[jumping]` tag altogether, or break it up into `[jumping-glitch]` and `[jumping-mechanic]`, or something of the sort.

Comment: Let's tell this tag to take a running *jump*.

Comment: But I could totally be an expert at jumping.

Comment: Leaving a similar comment here as I did on the dupe; as of today there are 0 [jumping] questions remaining. I've flagged for mod confirmation.